# Bracket locations in Java; Unsure of placement

Tags: java, brackets

Okay, so my first day in a real programming class. I'm excited but I don't understand how to know where brackets } { go.

Edit: For instance, this compiles fine but skips the last step to print "done". Seems that my online compiler was to blame: http://ideone.com Can anyone recommend something else?

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for (int x=1; x<=3; x++) {
        System.out.println("Number: " +x);  
        }
    System.out.println("Done!");        
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: What last step? Copy the relevant code into your question. Indent code appropriately.

Comment: Please [edit] the relevant portions of code into your question, and clarify what you mean by `skips the last step`. How does the output not match what you expect?

Comment: When I run your program it prints "Number 1" followed by "Number 2" followed by "Number 3" followed by "Done!". It does not skip any steps.

Comment: Running your program in Ideone also works fine. Whereas I fully agree with @alfa64 that an IDE would be ideal, it can be pretty intimidating at first - particularly if it's not being taught by your class. I suspect you may have accidentally bodged up the `for` logic previously.

Comment: I copied your code to that online compiler you specified and I got the expected output : 

Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download an IDE like Intellij Idea or Eclipse. Those programs will help you with the syntax errors and compile the code on your machine.
[Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)

Both are free.